# linux c socket token ring

Tags: c, linux, sockets

i'm trying to make a token ring network for homework using socket in a multiprocess application.
the error that i found is in the bind function when i call two or more times the application on the same port, and error in connect function when i try to connect to the server.

a server process must be connect to the next server and retrive info from the prec server (token ring network).

this is my wrong code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  "GET FROM ARGV, 
       int port: a port to connect"
       char *ip: ip address for the client to connect a server.
       int port_sux=a port to connect the client to server.
  "

  pid_t pid;


  pid=fork();
  if(pid==0){ //PROCESS SERVER.
    char string[100];
    int sd_server=crea_socket(porta);

    while(1){
        sd_client=accept(sd_server, NULL, NULL);

        read(sd_client, string, 100);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, string, strlen(string));

        close(sd_client);
    }
    close(sd_server);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else{   //PROCESS CLIENT.

        int sd_out=connetti_stazione(ip, porta_sux);

        write(sd_out, "client connesso", strlen("client connesso"));
 }
 return (0);
}


int crea_socket(int porta){
 int sd;
 struct sockaddr_in add;

 add.sin_family=AF_INET;                    
 add.sin_port=htons(porta);                 
 add.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);     

 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&add, sizeof(add))
 listen(sd, 1)<0){perror("\nErrore Listen."), exit(1);
}

int connetti_stazione(char *ip, int porta){
 int sd;
 struct sockaddr_in add_c;

 add_c.sin_family=AF_INET; 
 add_c.sin_port=htons(porta);
 inet_aton(ip, &add_c.sin_addr);

 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 if(connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&add_c, sizeof(add_c))<0)
 {
        perror("\nErrore connect."), exit(1);
 }

 return(sd);
}
```

Comment: *What* errors do you get? What does `perror` print?

Comment: And on an unrelated note, you should *really* declare your functions before you call them.

Comment: Please simplify the code sample and add an error message

Comment: i launch 2 application from shell. this two servers must be connected togheter. the problem is that the connect function fail.

server1 must send info to server2 and it must send info to server1

Comment: ah the perror return is "connection refused"